# How to run Junit Testsuite in Real time project

Tags: junit, junit4, testcase, test-suite

I made a test class A and B. Those test classes run separately fine. But if I try to run all in single Test Suite, I get the below error:

```
java.lang.Exception: class 'com.test.dev.Commonflow' (possibly indirectly) contains itself as a SuiteClass
    at org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError.<init>(InitializationError.java:38)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.addParent(RunnerBuilder.java:67)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:102)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:107)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.DefensiveAllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder$DefensiveAnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(DefensiveAllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:113)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.DefensiveAllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(DefensiveAllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:56)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:101)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:102)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:107)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.DefensiveAllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder$DefensiveAnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(DefensiveAllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:113)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.DefensiveAllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(DefensiveAllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:56)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:101)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:102)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:107)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.DefensiveAllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder$DefensiveAnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(DefensiveAllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:113)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.DefensiveAllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(DefensiveAllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:56)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.TestClassRequestResolver.createRunnerTestDescriptor(TestClassRequestResolver.java:55)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.VintageDiscoverer.lambda$discover$0(VintageDiscoverer.java:53)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.VintageDiscoverer.discover(VintageDiscoverer.java:55)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.discover(VintageTestEngine.java:62)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:177)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:164)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.<init>(JUnit5TestReference.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit5TestLoader.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.createTest(JUnit5TestLoader.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit5TestLoader.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

Below is the test suite class. Trying to run all test classes in single test suite class.

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({Commonflow.class, Utilsflow.class})
public class TestSuite {
    
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {    
        
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() {
        System.out.println("########END TenderTestSuite########");
    }
}
```

Test Class A :

```
public class Commonflow {

  //Some logics using  @Test
    
}
```

Test Class B :

```
public class Utilsflow {

  //Some logics using  @Test
    
}
```

Packaging Structure:

All test class and suite classes under src/test/java

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi King, Added it briefly Please assist

Comment: Cannot reproduce. This works fine for me.